# MacBook Pro (M1 Pro) freezes for a while after login

Tags: startup, performance, apple-silicon, ventura

I'm experiencing the following situation when booting my MacBook with MacOS Ventura 13.1.

1. I turn on the Macbook.
2. I successfully enter my user/password.
3. The OS starts loading but the progress bar freezes always at the same point (see attached photo).
4. After some time the screen turns off.
5. When the screens turn off, I press the power button and the OS finish booting.
6. I arrive at my desktop

[image: Frozen progress bar]

This happens in every power on. It is very inconvenient to have the screen to turn off and press the power button again to get the OS to fully boot. Any tip or idea to fix this?

Comment: Does the problem exist when you perform a Safe Boot (hold shift at boot)?

Comment: @benwiggy I've finally found the solution. Yes, it also happens in safe mode. I'll post an answer explaining what happened. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like I've solved.

I've to try several times until I can reach the startup options because it also freezes while loading. Finally, I've been able to boot into safe mode (*as [@benwiggy](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/198019/benwiggy) suggest in comments*). In this mode, it also freeze after doing the login.

At the end, I find out that the thing freezing all loadings is an SD Card that I always have connected to the laptop (*as extra storage*). Seems like the last version of Ventura has some problems booting while the card is plug-in (*previous version didn't give me any trouble*).

After realising and with the card unplug, I've rebooted the system several times, enter several times into the startup options and everything look normal again.